# Adobe Illustrator color correspondance issues

Tags: colors, adobe-illustrator

I've got a problem with Adobe Illustrator, with the colors. For example, I want to have a #00FF00 green on my shape. So i select my shape, i use my color selector tool, and I put 00ff00 in the dedicated field. I click on "OK" and... surprise! It's not a #00ff00 green, but a #6aa91f (C=64%, M=0, Y=100%, N=0) green.
Do you please have an idea to solve my problem? It would save my night! Thanks :))

[image: Issue illustration]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to change 'Document Color Mode' to RGB if you want to have the 'web-colors':

[image]

And since we are on SO, here is the script to change the document color mode, just in case:

```
app.executeMenuCommand('doc-color-rgb');
```